# C++ Shuffle Vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have seen other threads on this but none seem to answer my question. I'm trying to use the `shuffle()` function on a vector but I keep getting an error:

```
deck_of_cards.cpp:34:5: error: no matching function for call to 'shuffle'
shuffle (deck.begin(), deck.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
^~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:3049:10: note: candidate function [with
  _RandomAccessIterator = std::__1::__wrap_iter<Card *>, _UniformRandomNumberGenerator = std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271, 0,
  2147483647>] not viable: expects an l-value for 3rd argument
void shuffle(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm using clang++ as my compiler and this is my code that is throwing the error:

```
void DeckOfCards::shuffleDeck()
{
    seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    shuffle (deck.begin(), deck.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
}
```

I do have all the correct `#includes` in my program. I'm fairly new to C++ and this is basically a Java program that I have that I'm trying to convert to C++. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `std::shuffle` already? You're using `std` namespace for all the other references, why not for the `shuffle()` function?

Comment: I did try that already, and on the C++ reference page it left it out so I figured I'd try that. But it didn't work either way

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Technically, ADL will find it anyway, although I would personally specify it explicitly.

Comment: That's... really weird, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using clang++ specifically: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0

Comment: [I can't reproduce on clang 4.2.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eff5e2824ec62d67)

Comment: I'm using a vector of objects, would that make a difference?

Comment: It wouldn't. My only guess is that your stdlib is missing the correct overload of `std::shuffle`.

Comment: Is there a way to update it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it expects an lvalue ar third parameter, and you are giving it an rvalue (in the form of a temporary object).

Try this:

```
 auto gen = std::default_random_engine(seed);
 shuffle (deck.begin(), deck.end(), gen);
```

Note that [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) should accept an rvalue as third parameter, so a standards-compliant implementation would have accepted your code.

Comment: There's still the last argument for ADL. Wouldn't that one work regardless of `deck`'s iterator type?

Comment: I'm not aware of any overload for std::shuffle.  Every reference that I have seen only shows one declaration.

Comment: @shawn1874 You're right, it is not an overload. It is a template function with "universal references", so it should capture an rvalue with no problems.